# Delete all items in between (and including) two items in list

Tags: python, list, function, find

I'm trying to make a function that finds a 1 followed by a 2 inside the list and cuts it off, including everything in between it. It should work for however many 1-2 sections there are in the list.

For example:

```
sumOf12([1, 2, 2, 1, 99, 99, 2])
```

Should have an output of `[2]` because the first 1-2 is cut off.
`numList[3]` and `numList[6]` are also a 1-2 pair, so everything in between is cut off, too.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and naive approach:

```
def drop_between(xs, first, last):
    include = True
    for x in xs:
        if include:
            if x == first:
                include = False
            else:
                yield x
        else:
            if x == last:
                include = True



print(list(drop_between([1, 2, 2, 1, 99, 99, 2], 1, 2)))
```

Result:

```
[2]
```

Instead of using `yield` to create a generator (and then catching the results in a list with `list()`), you could of course just create an empty list and add results with `.append()` as you go.

However, if this runs into a `1` and a `2` never follows, all of the values starting with the `1` will still be dropped - perhaps that's not what you want?

i.e.:

```
print(list(drop_between([1, 2, 2, 1, 99, 99], 1, 2)))
```

Result:

```
[2]
```

A solution that keeps tracked of skipped items, so it can still yield those if no `last` marker is found:

```
def drop_between(xs, first, last):
    skipped = []
    for x in xs:
        if not skipped:
            if x == first:
                skipped = [x]
            else:
                yield x
        else:
            skipped.append(x)
            if x == last:
                skipped = []
    if skipped:
        yield from skipped


print(list(drop_between([1, 2, 2, 1, 99, 99], 1, 2)))
```

Result:

```
[2, 1, 99, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list or parameter "results"
Make a while loop. Optional: with exit condition, that eiter index of 1 or 2 provides back -1(not found).

Enter while loop and search index of 1. If not found, abort and add list to results. If found, search for index of 2 starting at index of 1. Same here, if index of 2 not found add everything to the list of results.
If both found, Remove everythig before index 1 and add it to results. Remove then everything from index of 1 to index of 2.
Continue with the while loop.

If you append to results list, there might be different options. If you just want to add the values to each other you can use an addition. If you want before to check your results, Creating a list seems to be better.

It could be that you want to have such a result [[2,3,4,1,4],[1],[2,2]] or such flat list [2,3,4,1,4,1,2,2]. Both is possible, but it depends on programming language how to solve this.

Use valid test data to check your results. Then, you will see if it works in each cases.